# Unlink не удаляет

Tags: php

Нужно удалить файл на этом же сервере, но по прямому пути. Например:

```
$imurl = "http://site.ru/images/img.jpeg";
unlink($imurl);
```

Конечно же, не работает. Как можно решить, не меняя значение `$imurl`?

Comment: Может, как-то можно отрезать от переменной "http://site.ru/"?

Comment: @Rammsteinik, зачем вам такие издевательства? Что вам мешает сделать так, как мы написали?

Comment: Придётся изменять 10000 записей в бд. Не проще ли отрезать начало у переменной?

Comment: @Rammsteinik, пфф.... кто же в базе абсолютные пути хранит? не надо так

Comment: А если место на сервере закончится, нужно будет ссылаться на картинки на другом сервере, тут без абсолютного пути не обойтись.

Comment: @Rammsteinik назначьте каждой картинке свой сервер. Просто вдруг site.ru домен уйдет случайно, что делать будете, 10000 записей менять. Не проще ли одну?)

Comment: @lampa, как понимаю, в бд добавить ещё одно значение, указывающее причастность к серверу?

Comment: @Rammsteinik таблицу с адресами серверов. В таблице картинок просто указываете идентификатор сервера. В этой же таблице можно указывать абсолютный путь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unlink($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/images/img.jpeg');` - это если апач у вас.

Answer (score 0):

Указывайте абсолютный путь по файловой системе, типа `home/domains/site.ru/images/img.jpeg`. Если не знаете путь к корневой папке, просто в `index.php` пропишите `echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];` и увидите.

Answer (score -1):

> Как можно решить, не меняя значение $imurl?

Никак (драматичная музыка). Нужно прописывать путь к файлу, можно заменять http://site.ru на document root, но подход изначально неправильный.